# How to wait for window to be hidden in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am hiding a Qt toolbox window in one of my functions. I need to do some screen capturing stuffs to be executed in function after hiding my toolbox window.

```
void ProcessData()
{
    Toolbox::getInstance()->hide(); //I am trying to hide toolbox here

    //screen capture stuffs.   -  It should be executed once the toolbox window is hidden.
}
```

But what happens is, Toolbox is hidden only when the ProcessData() returns. This leads to the problem that my captured screen have the toolbox.

Is there any way to wait for the toolbox to be hidden in Qt ?

Comment: Add `QApplication::processEvents` between `Toolbox::getInstance()->hide();` and `//screen capture stuffs.`.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from using `QApplication::processEvents`, I would suggest you a more elegant solution:

1. Reimplement [`QWidget::hideEvent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#hideEvent) of the class returned by `Toolbox::getInstance` to emit a signal, e.g. `widgetHidden`

   ```
   protected:
       void hideEvent(QHideEvent *event) {
           QWidget::hideEvent(event);

           Q_EMIT widgetHidden();
       }

   signals:
       void widgetHidden();
   ```
2. Connect `widgetHidden` to a slot to capture the screen

   ```
   connect(Toolbox::getInstance(), &MyWidget::widgetHidden, this, &ClassName::onWidgetHidden);
   ```

   where `MyWidget` is the class returned by `Toolbox::getInstance` and `ClassName` is the name of the class to which `ProcessData` belongs.
3. Add a flag to know if it is the right time to capture, as the widget might be hidden in some other way

   ```
   bool m_captureAllowed = false;
   ```
4. Implement the `onWidgetHidden` slot

   ```
   private slots:
       void onWidgetHidden() {
           if (m_captureAllowed) {
               m_captureAllowed = false;
               //screen capture stuffs
           }
       }
   ```
5. Set the flag in `ProcessData`

   ```
   void ProcessData()
   {
       m_captureAllowed = true;
       Toolbox::getInstance()->hide(); //I am trying to hide toolbox here
   }
   ```

Comment: @eyllanesc, thanks for the addition! Just one question: could you please tell me the benefit of using `Q_EMIT`? I always call the signals as normal functions without `emit` or `Q_EMIT`.

Comment: it is relative, the problem of using emit, signals, slot, etc is that they can come into conflict with other libraries.

Comment: @eyllanesc. I see. Thanks for the explanation!